# Help with Audits

Tags: discussion

I find this ridiculous. Seriously.

I'm going around review & notice an answer. I found a little common misconception and tell the user about it, and then get this:
[image] 
So this gives me a couple of ideas:

1. If I fail to many audit questions, will anything happen?
2. How can I comment on a good-quality audit?
3. If I pass an Audit, will I notified?
4. Can I nominate a question for an audit?

Comment: I probably _shouldn't_ be doing this, but, just click the 'link' button next to reviews and you'll see if it's a high quality post, or if nothing is there then you know it's low quality.

Comment: Also, I'm with @JourneymanGeek, review audits are stupid.

Comment: I stopped reviewing in the First Posts queue because of this defect: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/9248/design-flaw-in-the-review-audit-system.

Comment: You don't really tell us what action you selected.  If it was anything but "no action" that is likely the reason you failed.  [Here](http://superuser.com/questions/993121/what-is-the-significance-of-windows-file-names-that-have-hex-numbers-in-them-lik) is the question if anyone is interested

Comment: Honestly I think review audits are overall beneficial, but they are just poorly implemented.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. This (or something similar) was reported over a year ago;
   I thought it had been fixed since then.  Perhaps the Stack Exchange software
   [decayed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_rot).
2. Yes, screen shots are the neatest thing since sliced bread,
   but I can’t figure out exactly what yours is supposed to show —
   except for the dreaded **“STOP! Look and Listen.”** screen,
   which we’ve all seen before.
3. Audits are selected
   by a [man who lives in a shack on an uncharted planet](http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/profiles/RPVK2VZqX2qv6tQPTsLchK/man-in-the-shack). 
   He and his cat are the only inhabitants of the planet. 
   He is slightly crazy; this is reflected in the choice of the audit questions.
4. Seriously, audits are chosen randomly from real questions
   (or, in some cases, generated randomly). 
   The system assumes that any post with ≥5 up votes and no down votes
   must be “high quality”.  This is crazy;
   many low-quality posts get up-voted because it’s all just a popularity contest.
5. Seriously², if you spend any amount of time in the Review Queues,
   you are bound to encounter audits where the “right” answer is wrong. 
   As I said in point #2, we’ve all encountered that,
   and many of us have complained about it. 
   But, like the weather, nobody ever does anything about it.
6. As Journeyman Geek said, if your audit pass/fail ratio gets too bad,
   you will be banned from the Review Queue(s) — maybe only temporarily. 
   I’ve failed plenty of audits, and I’ve never had any consequences. 
   (Of course I’ve passed more than I’ve failed.)
7. Yes, when you pass an audit, the system tells you.
8. To nominate a question for an audit, contact the man in the shack.  :-)

Comment: I like this answer better. And considering  review audits, I do believe cats are involved.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: Thanks.  Can you clarify the rules (or point to a clarification) on what triggers a suspension, or is that one of those "secret algorithm" things?

Comment: Oh. I got hit by it. Twice. Quite secret tho I can tell you you need a fair number to get bitten be it.

Comment: For me, I've always found something is off with audit review questions/answers. Like a 'Low Quality' audit on what is quite clearly a well-written, well upvoted answer with no comments requesting clarification or saying *"No, this is wrong because [X]"*. Or other well-written ones with screenshots where the post owner is 'anonymous' - I always seem to scrutinise these ones fairly heavily and the 'deception' of the audit seems to unravel fairly quickly.

Answer (score 3):

1. You get suspended from reviews. Its a pain
2. No
3. Yes
4. No.