# Review Audit Failure

Tags: bug, review-audits

I just failed a [review audit](https://superuser.com/review/first-posts/473840) on this [Hard drive clicking for 16 times during startup](https://superuser.com/questions/1004670/hard-drive-clicking-for-16-times-during-startup)

I was just adding a comment to ask the OP if they could add their screenshots to the SE Imgur. Other than that I didn't see a problem with the question.

The review audit does not explain what I failed on. I can't improve if I don't know what I did wrong in the first place.

My question is, what did I do wrong?

Comment: You failed for this reason: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/9248/design-flaw-in-the-review-audit-system.  You had the audacity to comment on an upvoted question.  I wish the site programmers would fix that flaw.