# Let's empty out the First Posts review queue!

Tags: discussion, review

There are currently **750 questions** in the First Posts review [queue](https://superuser.com/review). I would like to encourage people to help to clean it up.

If everyone who has enough rep to participate will review at least couple of questions we can empty it out very quickly.

For comparison, the StackOverflow First Posts review [queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review) is currently **empty**. We should be able to keep it that way too.

[Let's do something about it.](https://superuser.com/review/first-posts)

Comment: I think it doesn't get cleared down as quickly because the actively participating population with enough rep is much much lower. Combine that with the 20 a day limit and I don't think we will ever fully clear the queue.

Comment: The number of reviewers might be higher if the audit logic wasn't flawed.  Audits are failed for adding any comment to a "good" question.  I, for one, gave up on that queue.

Comment: @fixer1234 They can't build audits that are 100 percent correct every time unless they include mod intervention in picking the posts. That would put a lot of work out there for the 200+ mods across the sites

Comment: I've been asking for more close votes for some time. I regularly use up my 50 / day well before 24 hours are up :/

Comment: @CanadianLuke: The problem is the audit logic, not selection.  There is nothing wrong with adding a comment to any post, especially for a new user.  The audit fails as soon as a comment is added rather than basing it on the action button selected.  Explanation of the problem here: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/9248/design-flaw-in-the-review-audit-system.

Comment: @Burgi, `I don't think we will ever fully clear the queue`. It was empty some time ago. I think just few months ago we kept it empty.

Comment: I believe that was over Christmas/New Year when the general traffic to the site was lower anyway. I don't have the statistics to back that up though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, we should definitely get people's first posts through the review system faster. The sooner they get feedback, the quicker they'll become accustomed to producing high-quality content.

Here are some things I'd like to say to people who want to help review posts:

- I'd suggest that you read [the community FAQ about this queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180030/295684) (written for Stack Overflow, but adaptable to reviewing in general).
- Remember that a single review in First Posts or Late Answers completes the review item, removing it from the queue. Therefore, you should fix all problems with the post or leave an explanatory comment with some pointers for the poster.

  - In the same vein, please feel free to use the Skip button if you're not sure what should be done with a post. There are plenty of posts that need review, I'm sure you'll find some items to definitively act on.
  - If you consistently are unsure about what to do in the face of a certain pattern of behavior, bring it up here on Meta. Bring specific cases so we can see what's going on. That way, everyone can benefit from the discussion.
  - Also, I'm sure people in chat would be happy to help you.
- You don't have to review the full 20 each day. Every solid, effortful review helps.
- You can use the "filter" link next to the queue name to see only items in certain tags. So if you know a lot about one area, you can filter for its tag(s) and work through just those items.
- Your review history is public (on your Activity page).
- Remember that reviewing is about improving the site and teaching people, not just pushing the queue length down or one's review stats up. If you're consistently unsure about what to do with posts in the queues, you can help the site in other ways, like editing or answering.

Oh, and there are other queues too, like Close Votes, which virtually always has a few hundred items.

All help is appreciated!