# One of those "trick" questions

Tags: discussion, support, bug

### Just chillin'

I was in <kbd>Review</kbd> and the below question popped up but in a different view not showing the votes as one of those "test" reviewer questions that grade you based on whether or not it feels you passed.

I believe the question in it's "fake" view had zero votes and no comments so I figured well I'll take a quick <kbd>**o{XXXX]::;;::;;:::^::^::^::>**</kbd> stab at a comment without any research for just an OP starting point.

### What I did. . .

I  wrote a "comment" about not knowing about "cost effectiveness" but based on the spec of 6 Gbps (or better) you'd probably want to look at some 10 GbE technology and consider all hops of interfaces and devices between the client and server (i.e. network gear, NICs, etc.).

So, I left a comment along those lines and then it popped up and said I need to pay better attention and that I failed. I thought at that moment "***WTF***" so I pressed the back button not knowing if it'd show me what I pressed after making the comment like <kbd>`I'm Done`</kbd> versus <kbd>`No Action Needed`</kbd> and obviously it doesn't work like that but I lost the failed screen to post.

[image]

### Question(s)

Let me think here of what to ask... uh.....

- Did I really do something wrong by leaving a comment and if so what would be considered more appropriate in this case?
- Is this some sort of automated algorithm that's just randomly part of the review operations for everyone including moderators?
- Are non-moderators allowed to know more about this process that does this grading process?
- Have there ever been "false-positives" for "failures" with this system in the past?
- Is this [Meta] the proper forum for such an inquiry on my part?

<sup><sup>**NOTE:** Sorry for the tags, I assume those are appropriate based on my assumption and the information I've obtained and disclosed.</sup></sup>

Comment: It happens to us all :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Did I really do something wrong by leaving a comment and if so what would be considered more appropriate in this case?

Apparently the system expects you to do nothing.

- Is this some sort of automated algorithm that's just randomly part of the review operations for everyone including moderators?

Yes. I've even been review banned before as a mod. Its designed to stop people from gaming the review queues. Its a pretty big problem on SO. It also occasionally discouraged people from reviewing

- Are non-moderators allowed to know more about this process that does this grading process?

Even us mods don't quite have all the details. After a while though, you kinda know what smells fishy, but that's experience rather than a knowledge of the inner workings of the system.

- Have there ever been "false-positives" for "failures" with this system in the past?

Yes.

- Is this [Meta] the proper forum for such an inquiry on my part?

I suppose. I've complained about such things in the past and at the very least gives us visibility on things.

Comment: Wow... An actual answer on SU Meta about this. Fantastic!! @JourneymanGeek to the rescue again!! Hopefully some of those non-answered SU Meta linked duplicates will actually link back to this moderator answered duplicate on the topic... I appreciate your helpfulness (as usual) Journeyman!!

Comment: Since you're a moderator, why don't you do anything about it? Either change the system so that commenting doesn't fail the audit, or if community moderators can't do that, you could tag [this question](http://meta.superuser.com/q/9248/513819) as [featured] or something.

Comment: Its a network wide setting and here we have roughly the same tools you do. I can and do complain on main and site meta sometimes and the CMs do read this. We can and do feed back such things to TPTB as appropriate.