# Audit reviews shouldn't treat comments as negative input

Tags: feature-request, review, review-audits

So I was reviewing first posts and came across a good question. Me thinking it has no answers yet, I left a comment asking for more information and suggesting a solution to the question. Afterwards, I wanted to upvote the question as it was good. However as soon as I left my comment I was greeted with the "You didn't pass" message:
[image]

I would suggest for audit posts to wait after someone left a comment. Comments don't always mean negativity. In the future I will upvote first, then comment, but I think this should still be addressed.

Comment: I'm sorry I missed that older question, it's three years old and there doesn't seem to be any progress or updates in the last years. Does the leadership even *want* this changed? I don't see why not and it's surely not a big effort to make these changes.

Comment: This is a network wide issue not just a SuperUser issue

Comment: I wondered about this too when I wrote asking about it here --> https://meta.superuser.com/questions/12185/one-of-those-trick-questions ... I assume there are many people that get hit by this at some point that wonder like we did when first seeing it before realizing it's not just us because when it says "*STOP! Look and Listen*" it's like saying "*You are an idiot, you messed all up with this*".... some people tend to want to understand what they did wrong with more detail and a chance to state what they did should have been fine, so I completely understand asking this question. LOL

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT Couldn't agree more. I've had false-positives happen before too, e.g. a question or answer was really bad but the system considered it good, or vice versa. So far it happened only 4-5  times in +250 reviews though, so I guess I'm good. But I agree, some more background information about this and how it works would be certainly great for new users.