# Failed a few tests recently for reasons that fail

Tags: feature-request, bug, review-audits

Just failed this test:
https://superuser.com/review/first-posts/644425

How did I fail? By commenting. I commented

> OMG. That made my heart hurt.

*Yes, the OMG wasn't necessary. The entire comment wasn't, but it was a comment of approval on a painful picture of horrific carnage.*

But Test Bot's automatic interpretation of my comment was incorrect. I'd guess the pass action on this would be an upvote or *No Action Needed* review.

There have been a couple other reviews I've done recently and also failed usually due to commenting where TB made assumptions about what my comment meant that were not accurate.

I'm not worried about failing too many tests. I've failed enough and passed enough and have enough rep it's just not an issue.

But I think TB perhaps ought to be tweaked a bit.

While it would be more work for mods (you know we love y'all), perhaps there ought to be two buttons on the *STOP, LOOK, LISTEN* message following failed audits:

1. You got me
2. I protest

Comment: Extremely relevant: [Design flaw in the review audit system](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/9248/design-flaw-in-the-review-audit-system)

Comment: amen. I've failed and felt it unfair before too... also order of operations matter....

Comment: Yea, the order of operations is what caught me once last week. I commented explaining the way forward on something that needed improvement, and then was going to downvote or close vote or something similar, but the audit failure showed up and ended that plan.

Comment: @music2myear - Indeed, you should have upvoted or selected "no action needed", this is because an audit considers leaving a comment to be the incorrect action for a quality contribution.

Comment: Related: [Review audits and “I understand” button](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/188780/195817),  [Create option to flag an audit [duplicate\]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/224490/195817),  [How do I challenge an audit failure?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/276155/195817), and maybe [Bring a “human factor” into review audit composition/selection](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/168374/195817).

Answer (score 4):

> I'd guess the pass action on this would be an upvote or No Action Needed review.

Exactly.  Your first thought would, preferably, been to upvote the high quality and helpful content.

Comments should primarily be used to indicate problems with the answer. This answer did not really need any more commentary and I suspect, but have not checked, that this answer got more than enough comments along the lines of "Ahhhh! Bad Thing!" which are not entirely helpful.

It is a nice picture, I admit.

<sub><sub>just checking...</sub></sub>

22 deleted comments.  All of them commenting on a pretty picture without adding much to the conversation or giving any useful insight.

Comment: Nice picture? NICE picture? That awoke carefully repressed memories and right now I'm still trying to convince my boss I need a binky and a blanket!

Comment: But seriously, while this specific case is admittedly not the best example, in most cases I think the audit bot should interpret the votes and flags and ignore the comments. For instance, if a post is less than a couple days old, has no comments, and needs improvement, I don't flag, I comment with direction. Only once direction has been ignored will I vote to close or flag. In mucking with times and comments to frame the situation, the audit bot throws this math off for me.

Comment: Yes, it is a nice picture.  Many an Old God would have loved to be able to create that level of mental anguish with just one simple image. (sorry for the harsh tone in the answer)

Comment: I apply an automatic +20% softening to answers from people with diamonds. No worries. :)

Comment: In all fairness though, the audits are an automated system and it is difficult to create anything more than simple rules that will apply across the network.  The rules for selection of audits have to be applicable to most sites and so occasionally people *will* fall afoul of those rules.  It's a sad fact, but not really a problem unless you persistently fail *every* audit, in which case the system will be doing its job.

Comment: True. Just chalk this up to one more (slightly but not really) frustrated user.

Answer (score 0):

I very much dislike failing an audit. I know I'm not to take it personally, but that's so hard for someone who strives to do *everything* with excellence. I feel your pain.

But I think an **I protest** button would create more problems that it would solve. It would invite reviewers to disagree with (typically correct) TB.  That invitation would flood Meta with complaints and claims of bleeding, overshadowing the instructive purpose of the audits.

TB, is an automated system. We all know such systems have their flaws. This is not an excuse for the flaws, but a reminder that ultimately what we must reach for in automation is *close enough* to perfection. As Mokubai pointed out, TB would have granted a passing grade had the action taken during the audit been correct (admittedly, in the strictest sense).

Given the tradeoffs I perceive with enabling users to protest their audit, I think TB's performance is "close enough."

Comment: You're probably right. I Protest would add loads of work with very minimal benefit.