# I messed up. What can I do? => This is an audit test

Tags: bug, review-audits

I just fell into the following "[audit test](https://superuser.com/review/first-questions/1241127)".

It's just a question of somebody saying "I messed up, can anybody help me?", such a question should not be an audit test!

Comment: How is this a bug? You failed to identify an unacceptable question.

Comment: "I have done "cut and paste", the cut was successful, not the paste, so many things are lost. Now what?" => nothing unacceptable about that.

Comment: You failed to identity that the question had already been deleted. Beyond that the question had been closed for over a month with numerous attempts to gain clarification. The question was properly closed and eventually due to not being improved automatically deleted after a period of time. What you describe isn’t a bug. You simply failed an Audit.

Comment: @Ramhound: I failed to see that this question had been deleted because it merely states being closed (not deleted) 10 days ago (not over a month). There's nothing wrong with saying that a question is ok if it's closed that recently. I'm not questioning the fact whether or not not this question should be closed/deleted or not. I'm questioning the speed on which innocent questions get turned into audit tests. I know this is done using an automated procedure and I'm pointing out that some parameters give this procedure a buggy feeling.

Comment: Questions that are closed are not "ok", closed questions should be improved, as they are closed for a reason. The question is over a month old, was closed almost over a month ago, thus it was eligible to become an audit question.  Likewise, "can anybody help me?", questions are not helpful to the community when the author fails to provide enough information to actually answer their question.

Comment: It's ok to fail these. I fail them, most people fail them. Just don't fail all of them and you'll be OK. There are some audits I feel the wrong decision was made on, and some of these I come back to after failing the audit and take actions based on my views.

Comment: @music2myear: you might be right, except for the fact that I'm banned from reviewing, apparently after having failed **just two** of them: if you need to fail a reasonable amount (let's say more than five), I wouldn't worry. But banning somebody already at two fails requests a stricter audit test policy.

Comment: Ah, your question didn't note that, and so I didn't consider it. How long is the first time ban? I'd add that fact you failed this bad one and are currently banned to your post to indicate this is more than just a failed audit.

Comment: @Ramhound I've seen questions getting downvotes and close votes that I feel shouldn't be closed. The community doesn't require group-think, and it is interesting learning the different more active community member's opinions and preferences through their vote actions. The system that pulls questions for audits could stand to be more capable of finding the stand-outs, probably through manual action.

Comment: @Dominique looking at your review history it is not just two reviews, that's just what is shown on your latest ban message. I'm seeing 8 review suspensions with 4 of those being in the last 3 months or so with somewhere like 11 audit failures across various categories. From the perspective of the system it sees you as a robo reviewer not paying enough attention. Yours is not the worst case I've seen (by far) but it is not "just" two reviews and historic bans are taken into account. I've seen some blatant robo reviewers with bans progressively increasing up to 6 months.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is advice I recall receiving when [I complained about failing an audit](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/12320/failed-a-few-tests-recently-for-reasons-that-fail) several years back:

It isn't necessarily about whether the question should be closed or not, but about whether you as a community member engaging in these moderator actions put forth the effort to know enough about the question to make a good choice when you are doing that.

So, on those I am unsure about, or feel some spidey-sense tingling regarding, I click through, out of the moderation queue, to the question itself. Then it is pretty clear whether this is an audit or not, and if it isn't I can get that further context that may help me better understand the entire context. I believe this is what audit system is trying to teach me, or remind me of, whether that is it's intended goal or not.